# opening a bookmark in firefox and chrome in incognito mode or private mode from browser not in private mode

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

How can I have **certain bookmarks always open up in incognito or private mode** when choosing them from the bookmark menu **when the browser is not in private mode**?  I'm using firefox and google chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an Add-on
[Private Tab Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/private-tab/)

Comment: Looks like this Add-on is no longer available. Have you found and alternative?

Comment: @SaqibAli No, Firefox no longer supports this..This Caused Security issues...Things change after 4+ years.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Firefox, but in Chrome, there's an extension that'll do that.  It's called Incognito Regex.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/incognito-regex-fixed-ver/okaigpjdjpcecnghfiegfopahbkcejak?hl=en

(Just make sure that when you add your bookmark domains, use the format 
`*mail\.google\.com` instead of `mail.google.com` , otherwise it won't work.)